# Nicer analytical expression for infinite sum

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits, summation

Is it possible to rewrite the following sum as a function of $x$ in a "nicer" form, where no sum appears?
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k \cdot \frac{1}{x^k - x^{-k}}
$$

Comment: Better? Better than what?

Comment: I meant "nicer". I updated the question.

Comment: So, nicer than what? What do you mean by "analytical expression"?

Comment: Nicer than as it appears. For example $1/(1-x)$ is nicer than $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} x^k$.

Comment: I edited again.

Comment: Ah, so you accept an infinite series as an analytcial expression. OK.

Comment: But I think the most recent edit has made things worse, as one solves problems and equations but not sums.

Comment: The technical term is "[closed form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression#Comparison_of_different_classes_of_expressions)".

Comment: No nice closed form is known. Otherwise, also the reciprocal Fibonacci constant (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_Fibonacci_constant) would have one.

Comment: As an aside, $~\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{k^5}{e^{2\pi k}-1}~=~\frac1{504}$.